# Reading content from a file stream c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, file-io, streamreader

I have a web api service that accepts file uploads.  The content of the file is a small JSON string like the following:

```
{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }
```

How do I get the file content while it is a stream instead of having to save the stream as a file on the web server and then open the file?

The following is my snippet:

```
byte[] fileData = null;
using(var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(httpRequest.Files[0].InputStream))
{
      fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(httpRequest.Files[0].ContentLength);
}
```

I'm using the 4.0 .NET Framework

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why not a `StreamReader`?

Comment: The question is how to I get the JSON from my stream.

Comment: If I use StreamReader, how do I get the JSON from my stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `StreamReader` class. Try this code:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpRequest.Files[0].InputStream))
{
    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var json = JObject.Parse(content);
    var name = json["name"];
}
```

Another option is to create a class for your json (manually or by http://json2csharp.com/):

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your code to this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpRequest.Files[0].InputStream))
{
    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(content);
    var name = person.name;
}
```